# function returns undefined in some pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load a javascript file asynchronously and the file contains this line defined within a plugin defaults. It returns correct return value in some pages whereas in other pages the same file returns 'undefined' values. Any pointers?

```
login: '<p>Log in with your '+ fnc(code).name +' account</p>'
```

somewhere at the bottom of the same file I have defined the function:

```
 function fnc(s){
      if(s =='' || s == 'a'){
        this.name = 'name1';
        this.value = 'value1';
      }else if(s == 'b'){
        this.name = 'name2';
        this.value = 'value2';
      }else{
        this.name = 'name1';
        this.value = 'value1';
       }
      return this;
    }
```

For some reason, the function returns 'undefined'

UPDATE: "code" is a global variable that is present in some other file, depending on the value of that variable, I want to return different values from the function

UPDATE2: I want to return multiple values from the function, updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: How is this function being ran?  `this` will be `window` unless you set its context.

Comment: What is `code`? Your function only sets `name` in three specific cases, so it (may) stay at `undefined` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` can refer to the document window, unless your writing an object, don't use `this`

```
function fnc(s){
    var rc = '';    
    if(s =='' || s == 'a'){
        rc = 'name1';
    } else if (s == 'b'){
        rc = 'name2';
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: right but now you won't get undefined, now you'll get an empty value instead or whatever `var rc` is set to. Still bad practice to have `this` floating in a function at the bottom of the page somewhere.

Comment: 'this' was the problem, it got fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` in that function is going to be either a reference to `window` or else `undefined`, depending on whether "strict mode" is in effect.

It really doesn't make a lot of sense for the function to be written like that.  Seems like it should just be:

```
function fnc(s) {
  return s == '' || s == 'a' ? "name1" : s == "b" ? "name2" : null;
}
```

Then you'd just call it as `fnc(code)` with no need for a "name" property. As somebody else pointed out also, you don't make provisions for when the "code" is something other than the empty string, an "a", or a "b".

Answer (score 2):

Are you passing a value to fnc other than '', 'a' or 'b', as it will return undefined

Comment: added 'else' condition to 'catch all'